# PDO Contraint Error 1062, but work is complete?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a strange situation where I am getting an error from my PDO statement, but the work is in fact being complete.

I am attempting to copy tables by first deleting the old data in the given table, and then writing new data from temp tables to the real tables.

```
$tables = array('tbl1', 'tbl2', 'tbl3');
foreach ($tables as $table) {
    $temp_table = $table."_temp";
    $stmt = $connection->query("DELETE FROM $table");
    $stmt->execute();
 
    $stmt = $connection->query("INSERT INTO $table (SELECT * FROM $temp_table)");
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

I placed a sleep in the middle to make sure it was working and my table data is deleted and then rewritten, but I am getting the following error:

```
Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

I am sure I am either missing something, or doing this in a way that it was never inteded to be done, but I really don't know which.
Any ideas?

Comment: After you run `$connection->query`, why do you then call `execute()`?

Comment: honestly, I thought it was needed. I know you call execute() with parameters when it's a prepare statement. I bet that's my entire issue (showing my n00bness).

Comment: I am not sure it's a data issue because if I do these SQL commands directly on the database it works. But yes, they are all unique and have values. The db is setup to have a primary key (the id) and it's auto-incremented, but you should still be able to enter a unique id

Comment: @NigelRen - your comment was the issue. Please submit as answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though this was a quick and easy fix, I am going to leave the question here in case someone else runs into this issue. After all, this site is for learning, right?

When doing a prepare statement, an execute statement is required because you are passing in the unknown parameters.

```
$stmt = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO users (`first_name`,`last_name`,`username`) 
                            VALUES (:first_name, :last_name, :username)");
$parameters = array(":first_name" => $user_details['first_name'], 
                    ":last_name" => $user_details['last_name'], 
                    ":username" => $user_details['username']);
$stmt->execute($paramArray);
```

However, when doing a standard query, an execute is not needed because no extra parameters are needed. In fact, adding an execute with a query simply duplicates the query.

```
$stmt = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM users");
```

There is a lot of documentation on this, but it's not always easy to find the answer, and some things (like this) simply aren't discussed. Here are some good sources:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

https://www.w3resource.com/php/pdo/php-pdo.php